# How to know if there is a different element in one array in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

My goal is to check if there are misplaced objects in one array.
for example the array is

```
   2.
   2.
   2.
   2.
   2.
   1.
   3.
   1.
   3.
   3.
   3.
   1.
   3.
   1.
   1.
   1.
   1.
```

I want to know if the first 5 elements, 6 to 13 and 14-17 are the same.

The purpose of this is to identify the misplaced elements in a clustering solution.

I have tried for the first 5 elements

```
   ISet=5
   IVer=7
   IVir=5
for i=1:ISet
       if(isequal(FIRSTMIN(i,1,2),FIRSTMIN(i+1,1,2))==%f)
           numMisp=numMisp+1
           mprintf("Set misp: %i",numMisp)

       end
   end
```

For the next 6 to 13 elements

```
    for i=ISet+1:IVer+ISet-1

        if(isequal(FIRSTMIN(i,1,2),FIRSTMIN(i+1,1,2))==%f)
            mprintf("%i %i Ver misp: %i\n",FIRSTMIN(i,1,2),FIRSTMIN(i+1,1,2),i)
            numMisp=numMisp+1
        end
    end
```

For the next 14 to 17 elements

```
for i=IVer+ISet:IVer+IVir-1
        if(isequal(FIRSTMIN(i,1,2),FIRSTMIN(i+1,1,2))==%f)
            mprintf("%i %i Ver misp: %i\n",FIRSTMIN(i,1,2),FIRSTMIN(i+1,1,2),i)
            numMisp=numMisp+1
            mprintf("Vir misp: %i",i)
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` for that purpose. For example the following test checks if the first five elements are the same

```
x=[2 2 2 2 2 1 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 1 1 1 1];
if length(unique(x(1:5))) == 1
//
end
```

You can do the the same for the other clusters by replacing `1:5` by `6:13` then `14:17`.

Comment: it only gets the unique value, not the occurrence of the different  value

Comment: Use the full syntax `[u,k]=unique(x)` (and read Scilab help page about this command).